The battery charge remains the same, as it was when Ubuntu was launched
15.6" Laptop ARDOR GAMING NEO G15-I5ND300 (NP5x_60_7x_RNx1)
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

When you start the computer, the percentage of charge does not move, neither up nor down. If the charger cable is connected.
Status in the tab: /Settings/Food/Battery level = Not charging.
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
  native-path:          AC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Вт 25 июн 2024 09:39:20 (647 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Вт 25 июн 2024 09:39:21 (665 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              35,6972 Wh
    energy-full:         48,664 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          73%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'

upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Notebook
  model:                BAT
  serial:               0001
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Вт 25 июн 2024 09:50:26 (26 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              35,6972 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         48,664 Wh
    energy-full-design:  52,514 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             16,315 V
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          73%
    capacity:            92,6686%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'

tlp-stat -c -s -b
--- TLP 1.6.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings:
defaults.conf L0006: TLP_ENABLE="1"
defaults.conf L0007: TLP_WARN_LEVEL="3"
defaults.conf L0008: TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT="0"
defaults.conf L0009: DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC="0"
defaults.conf L0010: DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT="2"
defaults.conf L0011: MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC="15"
defaults.conf L0012: MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT="60"
defaults.conf L0013: CPU_ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC="balance_performance"
defaults.conf L0014: CPU_ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT="balance_power"
defaults.conf L0015: NMI_WATCHDOG="0"
defaults.conf L0016: DISK_DEVICES="nvme0n1 sda"
defaults.conf L0017: DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
defaults.conf L0018: DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
defaults.conf L0019: DISK_APM_CLASS_DENYLIST="usb ieee1394"
defaults.conf L0020: DISK_IOSCHED="keep keep"
defaults.conf L0021: SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC="med_power_with_dipm"
defaults.conf L0022: SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT="med_power_with_dipm"
defaults.conf L0023: AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC="on"
defaults.conf L0024: AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT="auto"
defaults.conf L0025: AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_TIMEOUT="15"
defaults.conf L0026: PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC="default"
defaults.conf L0027: PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT="default"
defaults.conf L0028: RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC="auto"
defaults.conf L0029: RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT="auto"
defaults.conf L0030: RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC="default"
defaults.conf L0031: RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT="default"
defaults.conf L0032: WIFI_PWR_ON_AC="off"
defaults.conf L0033: WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT="on"
defaults.conf L0034: WOL_DISABLE="Y"
defaults.conf L0035: SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC="1"
defaults.conf L0036: SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT="1"
defaults.conf L0037: SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER="Y"
defaults.conf L0038: BAY_POWEROFF_ON_AC="0"
defaults.conf L0039: BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT="0"
defaults.conf L0040: BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
defaults.conf L0041: RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC="on"
defaults.conf L0042: RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT="auto"
defaults.conf L0043: RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_DENYLIST="mei_me nouveau radeon"
defaults.conf L0044: USB_AUTOSUSPEND="1"
defaults.conf L0045: USB_EXCLUDE_AUDIO="1"
defaults.conf L0046: USB_EXCLUDE_BTUSB="0"
defaults.conf L0047: USB_EXCLUDE_PHONE="0"
defaults.conf L0048: USB_EXCLUDE_PRINTER="1"
defaults.conf L0049: USB_EXCLUDE_WWAN="0"
defaults.conf L0050: RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP="0"
defaults.conf L0051: RESTORE_THRESHOLDS_ON_BAT="0"
defaults.conf L0052: NATACPI_ENABLE="1"
defaults.conf L0053: TPACPI_ENABLE="1"
defaults.conf L0054: TPSMAPI_ENABLE="1"

+++ System Info
System         = ARDOR GAMING Not Applicable NP5x_60_7x_RNx1
BIOS           = 1.07.05TDC
EC Firmware    = 7.2
OS Release     = Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Kernel         = 6.8.0-35-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 20 15:51:52 UTC 2024 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-35-generic root=UUID=fdce1df1-d219-4d69-8c06-98a44192c710 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Init system    = systemd v255 (255.4-1ubuntu8.1)
Boot mode      = UEFI
Suspend mode   = s2idle [deep]

+++ TLP Status
State          = enabled
RDW state      = enabled
Last run       = 09:59:14, 89 sec(s) ago
Mode           = AC
Power source   = AC

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: generic
Supported features: none available

+++ Battery Status: BAT0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = Notebook
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = BAT
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =      0 (or not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design             =   3410 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full                    =   3160 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now                     =   2318 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/current_now                    =      0 [mA]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Not charging

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_start_threshold = (not available) 
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold   = (not available) 

Charge                                                      =   73.4 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   92.7 [%]


tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.6.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: generic
Supported features: none available

+++ Battery Status: BAT0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = Notebook
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = BAT
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =      0 (or not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design             =   3410 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full                    =   3161 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now                     =   3161 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/current_now                    =      0 [mA]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Full

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_start_threshold = (not available) 
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold   = (not available) 

Charge                                                      =  100.0 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   92.7 [%]


Do I need to go through several discharge/charge cycles to stabilize the battery?
Will this affect the compatibility with the Windows that is installed next to Ubuntu?
Ubuntu stops the device charging process by 74% or 79%... and the charger turns off (randomly).

It looks like turning on the smart charging function, but I do not know how to control it.

Just out of interest, if you power down, leave it plugged in a while, then power on - does your battery charge level increase?

Yes, it can charge for up to several minutes, then stop before reaching 100% charge. Chaotic... If I restart the device with the charging cable connected, the charge simply freezes, the device does not charge.

Now, for example, this is not happening. I pulled out the charger cable and plugged it back in, but the charging doesn't work, it's just that the charge percentage froze.

Sounds like a hardware issue. Bad charger? Faulty power cable connection either into the charger or the connector at the machine?

The new device, works perfectly with Windows software. The connectors fit snugly into the computer socket, the computer can withstand the load of heavy games with a charger connected to it.

In the case of Ubuntu, I can't even hear the fan running, I only perform light operations, without any load and with the air conditioner turned on in the room.

I note what you've said about it working with Windows (are you really certain of that?) - but everything else sounds like a hardware problem. If it doesn't reach 100% when you leave it plugged in but turned off, it can't be anything to do with Ubuntu. Might be the charger, or the laptop, or the battery ... but I take your point if it works with Windows I'm confused! Charge freezing after booting just suggests the battery isn't drawing enough current to increase the charge level - either charger not delivering enough (most likely) or battery unable to charge.

If you can try a different charger I think that's your best option ... the fact the battery isn't doing down during use suggests some current is going in; the battery going up a bit when plugged in and powered off suggests the battery can accept some charge - I suspect your charger just isn't delivering enough juice to power the laptop and charge the battery -- though what you're reporting is a bit hard to understand (ie working with Windows bit).

I had experience working here on this site with a Wind 11 Pro device, at that time I was told the same thing as now that my device is bad and it does not have the original battery. I was buying a bunch of batteries until one day I was told that I had to add a certain line to the blacklist of module downloads. I'm just not going to run anywhere, buy a new charger or batteries, just because, in your opinion, my device is bad...I noticed a tendency that if the equipment is Russian or Chinese and its parameters do not pass logging with European standards, I am sent to buy good equipment.

My laptop is new, functional and works great with Windows software. Only Ubuntu has problems. And this security system, which the developers have been working on for many years, is just an even attempt to keep the market of goods of a certain range. Because of this, I will not run breaking my legs along the way... to buy something that is not present in the Ubuntu codes.

I don’t think anyone sent you to buy anything, and I don’t think anyone knew where your equipment was made. (I’m using a cheap Chinese charger on my laptop & it’s fine!). But what you described still doesn’t sound like an Ubuntu problem - you described an issue that persisted  when the laptop was powered off, so at least we can say Ubuntu isn’t causing your problem. Looks like you’ve solved it anyway - well done.

You said to try another charger, but to do this, I need to buy one. I'm only worried about one thing, if the person who changes the control center driver settings and installs Ubuntu as the only axis on his computer, how long will it take him to charge his device to 100% and whether he will be able to find a solution. After all, there are no such settings in the BIOS.

You have not mentioned the make model of your laptop.
But seems like charging threshold has been applied to laptop. It is an option given by manufacturer to keep the battery state from degrading faster, if the charger is always plugged in.
If charging threshold applied was 80 - 75 it will just keep the battery afloat within that range.
Also when it is in this mode the upower will report state as pending-charge so that why the icon shows as it is disconnected (not charging) which is normal and is how Gnome Desktop enviroment reports it.
since you have installed TLP, TLP has this functionality of setting charging threshold.
Refer to this documents.
https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#faq-how-to-set-thresholds
You can also do it using command line directly without TLP but it depends on the make or model of the laptop.
You can check command-line for different laptops here
https://maniacx.github.io/Battery-Health-Charging/device-compatibility
Also you can use gnome-extensions, it also has the option to change the behaviour of charging icon to show is as charging instead of discharging when laptop is limiting charge due to battery threshold (similar to how it does on windows).
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5724/battery-health-charging/

Hi. You will see the device name in the code output above ARDOR GAMING Not Applicable NP5x_60_7x_RNx1. I have pinned the output of the tlp-stat -b  command (although it is also above)... The output Supported features: none available tells us that the threshold value is not supported.

This quote is similar to the problem of displaying the name of my device... "Some models are not recognized as ThinkPads because of an incorrect model string provided by coreboot. As a result battery care is not activated (see Issue #657). Sample output of tlp-stat: Supported features: none available ".

Try the following.
• Disable smart charging or charging threshold options in BIOS, if available.
• Disable smart charging or charging threshold options in Ardor OEM software in Windows, if available.
• You can also try resetting the embedded controller, by powering off the laptop and holding the power button for 30 seconds.
• Resetting the BIOS to factory defaults also might help.
• Try Gnome Extension Battery Health Charging, It will notify if your laptop is unsupported or supported with dependencies required. But note that using unofficial kernel modules, use it at your own risk.

That's the problem, that only point two works. The control center, in addition to the threshold value of the charge, also controls the operation of the CPU, cooling fan, keyboard backlight and much more... If I do not switch all the settings in this program (driver) in advance, later if I install Ubuntu as the only axis on my laptop, then I will not be able to control these parameters, the paramerts will remain the same as I left them through Windows.

The extension Gnome Extension Battery Health Charging is not supported.

Look like your laptop is one of Clevo's barebone. If it is, it might be work looking at these.
https://github.com/Slimbook-Team/slimbook-qc71-dkms
https://github.com/tuxedocomputers/tuxedo-drivers

This program is installed by OEM, Control Center Package.
A driver for Windows that affects the operation of the BIOS.
If you notice that your device is not charging to 100% charge, you need to install Windows and this driver for power management )
Otherwise, you will be sent to buy a new power adapter.
acpi -V
Battery 0: Charging, 96%, 00:22:00 until charged
Battery 0: design capacity 3410 mAh, last full capacity 3228 mAh = 94%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, 42.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 120.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 1: TCPU_PCI no state information available
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 3: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 8: INT3400 Thermal no state information available
Cooling 9: intel_powerclamp 0 of 100
Cooling 10: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 11: TCPU no state information available
Cooling 12: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 13: iwlwifi_1 no state information available
Cooling 14: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 15: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 16: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 17: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 18: SEN2 no state information available
Cooling 19: TCC Offset 2 of 63







If, for example, I set the fan settings to maximum, make the keyboard red, these parameters will remain when Ubuntu is started. And Ubuntu won't be able to change them. Fan parameters, keyboard colors, battery charging threshold and much more... unavailable.
https://ardor-gaming.com/drivers/29514097/neo/
